# Is there a cultural belief in Brazil or Spain that frowns upon brushing one's teeth / spitting in the kitchen sink?

Tags: local-customs, culture, brazil, portugal

I was recently told by my Brazilian roommate not to brush my teeth in the sink (I wasn't, I just spit in it) because of cultural reasons. Is there a cultural norm in Brazil / Portugal where this behavior is frowned upon?

Comment: Well, doing that in the kitchen sink wouldn't be normal in the US or (afaik) much of Europe either, barring some exceptional circumstances like  a very crowded apartment

Comment: Yes, we have 1 bathroom for the 4 of us and in the morning it gets quite busy. My question is more, "is there a cultural belief against doing it" vs. "is it normal". It's probably not normal in most 1st world countries, but there's no cultural belief against it either.

Comment: It's not normal anywhere in the world. Why would there need to be a special belief in Brazil?

Comment: @JonathanReez, Yes I understand it's not normal. I'm asking specifically if it is considered rude to do so in Brazil. Like I said, there's 4 of us and 1 bathroom so everyone needs to use it in the morning. The Brazilian tenant specifically said she would like us to stop brushing our teeth in the kitchen sink because it is "against her culture".

Comment: That's the point: it's against global culture, not just Brazilian.

Comment: @JonathanReez Is it really against global culture? I wouldn't consider it rude to brush teeth in the kitchen here in Australia. Unusual, but not rude.

Comment: @TimMalone it's on the same level as peeing in the shower: lots of people do it, but some find it offensive. Nothing country-specific.

Comment: frowned ? no. it just looks weird.

Comment: You've misunderstood him. It's not against Brazilian culture but agaist personal culture. It's unhygienic and disgusting. It's not travel related.

Comment: @JonathanReez It's really, really not on the same level as that! It'd be the norm to see it as unusual, but not offensive or disgusting, 'contaminating' a communal space with a taboo action as your example is widely viewed. If you've got facts or experience to back up "nothing country specific" in Brazil, post it as an answer

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo if you can back that up with relevant facts or experience in Brazil, that's the answer to the question

Comment: Note that Brazilian culture originates from Portugal. I hope you don't mind me amending the post.

Comment: @JonathanReez, when I said "or Spain" I didn't mean to imply that Brazilian culture came from Spain. It was just because I heard the same from a friend who has a Spanish roommate.

Comment: @JonathanReez I disagree calling it 'not normal', most families I know brush their teeth in the kitchen because of small or overcrowded bathrooms in the morning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching for "[brushing teeth in kitchen sink](https://www.google.cz/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=brushing%20teeth%20in%20kitchen%20sink)" returns hundreds of forum posts about this very topic, spread over several English-speaking countries. This leads me to believe that this is a global custom, rather than just a Brazilian quirk.

On a personal level, the aversion to brushing teeth in the kitchen is explained by several reasons:

1. It's unusual. Likewise eating in the bathroom is a bit strange.
2. Different levels of cleanliness between the kitchen and the bathroom.
3. Watching someone brush teeth is rarely a pleasant sight. That's the reason why Hollywood movies never show people using toothpaste and why everyone brushes with their mouth closed.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3-ywpMj4Jk - Doesn't strike me as unpleasant

Answer (score 10):

No. Some people can find that weird and some can argue it's not appropriate to do personal hygiene in the kitchen but that's no different in Europe or North America IMHO. Just talk it with your roomate and maybe you can reach an agreement. I can guess the need can arise in a small apartment with lots more people than bathrooms. If your room mate continues to disagree, propose to use a bucket.

I live in Brazil and have lived here for more than 30 years in many towns in Northern and Southern regions. Also has traveled a lot and know a bit of the main cities like São Paulo, Rio de Janeiro, Salvador, Curitiba, Porto Alegre, etc.